# Laravel package not reading bootstrap

Tags: laravel, pdf, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using `barryvdh/laravel-snappy` package but it's not reading bootstrap properly, can anybody tell me how can i fix that? or it's an issue with the package?

Comment: can you show the exactly error are you having?

Comment: @AlfredoPaz no errors, but when i generate it and download it the layout gets messed up with the grid-system

Answer (score 0):

barryvdh doesnt support external css files. You have to define your own styles inline

Comment: the problem here is with the bootstrap, I'm using the col-xs-n only but all of the columns are appearing on top of each other